# Can we use protractor for automation testing in Native Android or IOS application with appium

Tags: android, ios, protractor, appium, e2e-testing

I have a native android and ios app. Which is the best way to its test automation. Is there any way to use protractor testing tools for native mobile application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is Yes.

More Detailed Answer. Their was a [TEAM TODO](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1940) - Feature Request created for this.

Checkout this [#issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1798) which specifically talks about Native apps and latest comments

Protractor - Appium  to test applications on mobile browsers is an established process.You can find lot of [documentation here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md)

Protractor - Appium support for Hybrid and Native apps has been implemented but I never tried to know the ground reality :)